# DJANGO: create a button that allows to download a zip file

Tags: python, django, button, zip, archive

I've created a little site with django: i'd like to insert a button that allows the user to download a zip file.
How could i make it?
I can't find the right tool to do that.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this zip file is stored in the Static or Media sections of the project, you should be able to link to it by making a call in the template such as `a href ="{% static '[zip file location]' %}"` the way you would for the reference to a script or image.

If you're not used to working with your static files, you can find more information about it [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: settings.py:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

i have dirs static/home in the main folder of the project.

button:
<li><a href ="{% static "home/1.1.rar" %}">1.1 - OpenOrd - Centrality</a></li>

it says: "'home\1.1.rar' could not be found"

Comment: Can you use F12 and select the element to see what the full url/path it's pulling is, and if it matches what it should be based on the rar file's location? Also you might want to replace the double quotes around home/1.1.rar with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

first, configure your static file like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/static/',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I think you might miss the '/static/' part. then, use a hyper link point to your file.